# Laravel 4 applying custom filters to routes - error undefined offset

Tags: php, laravel, filter, authorization, laravel-routing

Trying to prevent non-admin users from accessing certain pages. I must not be doing it correctly though because I'm getting back an error of `undefined offset: 1` while trying to access an admin only page while logged in as an admin.

Filter

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
if (!Auth::user() || Auth::user()->permissions != 1) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Routes

```
Route::resource('deals', 'DealsController');

Route::resource('blog', 'PostsController');

Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('deals/create', 'DealsController');
    Route::get('blog/create', 'PostsController');
});
```

I can't put the filter on a constructor of my deals or blog controller because the index page for each of those routes needs to be accessible to all users. When I'm not logged is as an admin, the routes function correctly and redirect back to the home page when trying to visit a page that is admin-only. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Post your `User` model's code.

Comment: Is it possible that your User->permissions returns an array?

Comment: I just added the `User` model's code. And @iavery I'm not sure if its returning an array, how can I find that out?

Comment: dd(Auth::user()->permissions) will tell you exactly what it is returning. Since it's not a relationship, it should just be returning whatever the value of users.permissions is. Having the User model helps :)

Comment: When adding `dd(Auth::user()->permissions != 1))` on my filter and attempting to go to the page that is admin only while being logged in as an admin, all I see is a blank page that says `boolean false`.

Comment: The dd() function in Laravel simply prints out the type and value of the variable it is passed and then dies (prevents the process from continuing past that point). You want to use 'dd(Auth::user()->permissions' to get the permissions value for your current user (leave of the '!= 1'). Either way, since that came back as false we know that you User has a permissions value of 1. Is it possible that the undefined offset error is occurring after the routing is completed (in your controller or template)? Undefined offset means that it is trying to access an index that does not exist on an array.

Comment: Thanks for your help @iavery I just found the solution.

Comment: Awesome, and no problem. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the problem, it was occurring because of the routing. Trying to apply a route group with a filter to routes that had already been defined as a resource. When I removed the group routes and did some research on using the `beforeFilters` in a constructor, I found that I can exclude a function, thus solving my problem.

This line of code was the solution

```
$this->beforeFilter('admin', array('except' => 'index'));
```

I hadn't know that I could use the except property, but now it all works well.